# Bootstrap Show active link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show the active link for the navigation drop down if one of the dropdown-menu are chosen

this is a simple navigation without dropdown and it work

```
<li class="<%= 'activen' if current_page?(jobs_path) %>" ><%=  link_to "Offres d'emploi" , jobs_path, class:"active-shadow" %></li>

<li class="<%= 'activen' if current_page?(profiles_path) %>"><%=  link_to "Découvrir des utilisateurs" , profiles_path, class:"active-shadow" %></li>
```

and this is my dropdown

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Entreprises <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><%=  link_to "Découvrir des Entreprises" , companies_path %></li>
<li><%=  link_to "offres par entreprises" , offre_path %></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be the same idea, but you may need to change the colour of active as it may be the same

...

```
<li class="<%= 'activen' if current_page?(companies_path) %>" ><%=  link_to "Découvrir des Entreprises" , companies_path %></li>

<li class="<%= 'activen' if current_page?(offre_path) %>" ><%=  link_to "offres par entreprises" , offre_path %></li>
```

...

EDIT:

Re-reading your comments, you want if you are in the "Découvrir des Entreprises" or "offres par entreprises" page, you want the active effect on the "Entreprises" right?

...

```
- if current_page?(companies_path) || current_page?(offre_path)
  <li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="active dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Entreprises <b class="caret"></b></a>
....
```

Comment: if the companies_path is active or the offre_path i want the active link in the dropdown link in the navbar

Comment: just understanding, you want to replace the "Entreprises" to be either  the "Découvrir des Entreprises" or "offres par entreprises" text?

Comment: yes I want when I am in the "Découvrir des Entreprises" or "offres par entreprises" the active link should be "Entreprises"

Comment: You can also use the controller to determine "current" location if you have multiple actions, so that it's not as fine grained as checking each path.  Use `params[:controller] == "companies"` instead of `current_page?(companies_path)`